# Replace ** to NULL in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, regex, find-and-replace

I have excel which contain ** as value along with other values across between Rows and Column. I'm trying to replace ** with NULL but using Find & Replace it's Replacing everything as it's taking ** as Regex operation.

I tried Find entire cells only & Match Case as well but I got same result.

Comment: Do you know the purpose of [**the tilde**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/using-wildcard-characters-in-searches-ef94362e-9999-4350-ad74-4d2371110adb)? Use `~*~*`

Comment: thanks, was not aware about it.